# Android/Java common json import interface

Tags: java, android, json, interface, import

I'm writing an Android app which is able to export the current state of an `Activity` or `Fragment` to a JSON-file, which has the following common format:

```
{
  "data": {
    "result": {
      <content depends on specific class>
    },
    "input": {
      <content depends on specific class>
    }
  },
  "identifier": <identifier depends on specific class>,
  "version": 1
}
```

This means that `Activities`/`Fragments` which have the ability to export fill in the marked contents implementing an interface which I called "Exportable" and the overall export function calls the methods defined in the interface. This is a straigt forward solution which works quite well.

So far so good. Now I want to make the inverse direction. I want to load a file and call the corresponding `Activity`/`Fragment` dependent on the content of the identifier.

Reading the content of the "input" and the "result" shall be done by a method of the `Activity`/`Fragment` itself.

Unfortunately this is not obvious to me how to solve this problem in an elegant way.
What is the best way to do that? The solution shall be as abstract as possible so that it can easily be extended.

Comment: What aboot using [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to save and restore `Activity` state? This also survives application/device restarts. If you just want to keep short-lived state (device rotation, backgrounding), you could use the built-in [`savedInstanceState` `Bundle` system](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

Answer (score 0):

There could be so many different answers to this. Google has a library called GSON, which can automatically read and write JSON data to and from Java classes. If you don't want to use a library, you can use Java reflection.

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject js= new JSONObject("data");

JSONObject jSObject1=js.getJSONObject("result");
JSONObject jSObject2=js.getJSONObject("input");
and so on
i hope i understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

An if-else would be the simplest solution, but if it is not abstract enough for you, use the [Abstract Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

Create an `ExportableFactory` interface that defines a method to create an `Exportable`, and implementations of this interface for `Activity` and `Fragment`. Then create a `Map<String, ExportableFactory>` that maps the possible values of `identifier` to the right factory. Then call:

```
Exportable exportable = factoryMap.get(identifier).createExportable(data);
```

That way, if you want to add a third implementation of `Exportable`, you will just have to create the corresponding implementation of `ExportableFactory` and add it to the map, without modifying the calling function.